# How to find out the total number of virtual core your CPU has

Tags: windows-7, cpu, multi-core, intel-core-i5

This is the [specification](http://ark.intel.com/products/67355/intel-core-i5-3210m-processor-3m-cache-up-to-3_10-ghz-rpga) of my computer however i have problem finding out how many virtual cores are there in total .

I would like to know if there is any command in windows 7 which would help me determine the number of virtual cores my CPU has

Comment: The link you provided is for all i5 processors, not your particular processor.  System (Win + Break) should show your specific processor, and you can look it up in that table.  I'm also not sure what you mean by a virtual core.  Modern CPUs often have multiple cores on a single chip.  Sometimes, those cores have hyperthreading that results in behavior similar to having more cores.

Comment: @ernie what do you mean by Win + Break ??? yea , i think virtual core means hyperthreading

Comment: So your system has 2 cores, which are hyperthreaded, so they'll appear like 4 cores in some cases.

Comment: @Computernerd, hold down the Windows key, and press the Break key. If you have one, not all keyboards do. It'll be at upper right, and may also have a "Pause" label.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can pull the information from WMI via PowerShell:

`PS> WmiObject -class win32_processor -Property Name, NumberOfCores, NumberOfLogicalProcessors | Format-List -Property Name, NumberOfCores, NumberOfLogicalProcessors`

Will produce something like:

```
Name                      : AMD Phenom(tm) II X4 955 Processor
NumberOfCores             : 4
NumberOfLogicalProcessors : 4
```

Add a `-computername <computername>` argument and you can pull the info from networked computers as well.

Answer (score 4):

Try the following from a command prompt:

`wmic cpu get name,numberofcores,numberoflogicalprocessors`

As noted by techie007 in his answer, you can pull information from remote computers by adding a `/node:<computername>` between `wmic` and `cpu`, and replacing `<computername>` with the name of the host you would like to query. The `/node:` parameter can be used on any WMIC query, not just this one.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a software such as Everest, or the freeware [CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html) to find out your system specifications. If you boot a Linux Live CD, then just open the System Monitor.

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> to open Task Manager and switch to *Performance* tab. There will be one CPU graph for each virtual core.

On Windows 8 you'd have to expand Task Manager's window first (*More details* button) and switch graph type because it displays overall graph by default.

Comment: If you only want to know the number of virtual cores, this is the way to find out.

Comment: This method doesn't distinguish between physical cores and logical cores . . . no way when I see 4 to know if it's 2 hyperthreaded cores, or if it's 4 physical . . .

Comment: @ernie OP explicitly asked for "virtual" ie. logical cores.

Comment: The resource monitor can provide better clues, the virtual cores will show "parked" when mostly idle.